# XML to SQL Table Query

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

This is my XML stored in a row. How do I convert it to insert into a table using a T-SQL query in the following table format?

```
<ENVELOPE>

    <DSPVCHDATE>16-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>PRASHANT MEHTA 359244</DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Sale</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPINBLOCK>
        <DSPVCHINQTY></DSPVCHINQTY>
        <DSPVCHINAMT></DSPVCHINAMT>
    </DSPINBLOCK>
    <DSPOUTBLOCK>
        <DSPVCHOUTQTY>1 Pcs</DSPVCHOUTQTY>
        <DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>23046.88</DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>
    </DSPOUTBLOCK>
    <DSPCLBLOCK>
        <DSPVCHCLQTY></DSPVCHCLQTY>
        <DSPVCHCLAMT></DSPVCHCLAMT>
    </DSPCLBLOCK>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2612)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>


    <DSPVCHDATE>19-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>XYZ Company</DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Purchase</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPINBLOCK>
        <DSPVCHINQTY>1 Pcs</DSPVCHINQTY>
        <DSPVCHINAMT>23437.50</DSPVCHINAMT>
    </DSPINBLOCK>
    <DSPOUTBLOCK>
        <DSPVCHOUTQTY></DSPVCHOUTQTY>
        <DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT></DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>
    </DSPOUTBLOCK>
    <DSPCLBLOCK>
        <DSPVCHCLQTY>0 Pcs</DSPVCHCLQTY>
        <DSPVCHCLAMT></DSPVCHCLAMT>
    </DSPCLBLOCK>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2613)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
</ENVELOPE>
```

This is the required output format.

Issue is I do not have a record separator in raw xml. Each new records starts with a `<DSPVCHDATE>`

[image]

Comment: This is a very annoying, and really badly formatted XML - it would be **much easier** if each row you want to extract where inside its own separate XML element, e.g. `<DATAROW><DSPVCHDATE> ......` etc. With the current format, it's next to impossible to get a proper output - at least in T-SQL. Can you influence the shape of the incoming XML in any way?

Comment: Issue is I do not have control over XML output. 3rd party software sends this XML data which I do not have control. I agree with you. But I have to find some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` to navigate the nested elements of xml content.
Given the inconvenient structure of this XML, it can be changed into something useable as follows, by adding a containing node called `<ThisNode>`.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '
<ENVELOPE>

    <DSPVCHDATE>16-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>PRASHANT MEHTA 359244</DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Sale</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPINBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHINQTY></DSPVCHINQTY>
      <DSPVCHINAMT></DSPVCHINAMT>
    </DSPINBLOCK>
    <DSPOUTBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHOUTQTY>1 Pcs</DSPVCHOUTQTY>
      <DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>23046.88</DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>
    </DSPOUTBLOCK>
    <DSPCLBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHCLQTY></DSPVCHCLQTY>
      <DSPVCHCLAMT></DSPVCHCLAMT>
    </DSPCLBLOCK>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2612)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>


    <DSPVCHDATE>19-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>XYZ Company</DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Purchase</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPINBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHINQTY>1 Pcs</DSPVCHINQTY>
      <DSPVCHINAMT>23437.50</DSPVCHINAMT>
    </DSPINBLOCK>
    <DSPOUTBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHOUTQTY></DSPVCHOUTQTY>
      <DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT></DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>
    </DSPOUTBLOCK>
    <DSPCLBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHCLQTY>0 Pcs</DSPVCHCLQTY>
      <DSPVCHCLAMT></DSPVCHCLAMT>
    </DSPCLBLOCK>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2613)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>

</ENVELOPE>'
```

This can be converted to useable XML as follows:

```
WITH 
cte AS (Select REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @XML, 1), N'<DSPVCHDATE>', '
  </ThisNode>
  <ThisNode>
    <DSPVCHDATE>'), N'</ENVELOPE>', N'
  </ThisNode>
</ENVELOPE>')  AS str)
SELECT @XML = CAST(STUFF(str, CHARINDEX(N'</ThisNode>', str), LEN(N'</ThisNode>'), N'') AS XML)
FROM cte
;
```

query

```
SELECT
      A.evnt.value('(DSPVCHDATE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHDATE
     ,A.evnt.value('(DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT
     ,A.evnt.value('(DSPVCHTYPE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHTYPE
     ,A.evnt.value('(DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT
     ,A.evnt.value('(DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER

     ,B.rec.value('(DSPVCHINQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHINQTY
     ,B.rec.value('(DSPVCHINAMT/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHINAMT 

     ,C.rec.value('(DSPVCHOUTQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHOUTQTY 
     ,C.rec.value('(DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT/text())[1]','float') AS DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT 

     ,D.rec.value('(DSPVCHCLQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHCLQTY 
     ,D.rec.value('(DSPVCHCLAMT/text())[1]','int') AS DSPVCHCLAMT 

FROM @XML.nodes('/ENVELOPE/ThisNode') A(evnt)
OUTER APPLY A.evnt.nodes('DSPINBLOCK') B(rec)
OUTER APPLY A.evnt.nodes('DSPOUTBLOCK') C(rec)
OUTER APPLY A.evnt.nodes('DSPCLBLOCK') D(rec)
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b52cc30e40f6cd2a3fb909f080890b5)

Comment: Yes, the structure is quite unpleasant and only causes the element to repeat.

Comment: If you can come up with a way to convert the OP's XML to your XML in SQL Server automatically, *then* you could apply the rest of your answer.  I think that I can show how to do that, if you want.

Comment: Yes, if possible, you can show me the automatic xml conversion

Comment: If it's already in SQL Server then this is the correct way.

Comment: adding some nodes manually outside SQL will not be possible at least in my case.

Comment: The structure can be modified once and for all. When such a problem is found in the data, the information structure must be corrected for whatever reason the error occurred.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi I have updated your answer with my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method by using pure XQuery. No need to do any string manipulation, CASTing, etc.

All elements inside the root element `<ENVELOPE>` constitute an Arithmetic Progression. Elements that grouped by their position: 1 - 7, 8 - 14, etc. should be placed inside the encompassing `<row>` element.

It creates the following XML on the fly:

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <row>
    <DSPVCHDATE>16-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    ...
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2612)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
  </row>
  <row>
    <DSPVCHDATE>19-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    ...
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2613)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
  </row>
</ENVELOPE>
```

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<ENVELOPE>

    <DSPVCHDATE>16-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>PRASHANT MEHTA 359244</DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Sale</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPINBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHINQTY></DSPVCHINQTY>
      <DSPVCHINAMT></DSPVCHINAMT>
    </DSPINBLOCK>
    <DSPOUTBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHOUTQTY>1 Pcs</DSPVCHOUTQTY>
      <DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>23046.88</DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>
    </DSPOUTBLOCK>
    <DSPCLBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHCLQTY></DSPVCHCLQTY>
      <DSPVCHCLAMT></DSPVCHCLAMT>
    </DSPCLBLOCK>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2612)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>

    <DSPVCHDATE>19-4-2021</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>XYZ Company</DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Purchase</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPINBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHINQTY>1 Pcs</DSPVCHINQTY>
      <DSPVCHINAMT>23437.50</DSPVCHINAMT>
    </DSPINBLOCK>
    <DSPOUTBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHOUTQTY></DSPVCHOUTQTY>
      <DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT></DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT>
    </DSPOUTBLOCK>
    <DSPCLBLOCK>
      <DSPVCHCLQTY>0 Pcs</DSPVCHCLQTY>
      <DSPVCHCLAMT></DSPVCHCLAMT>
    </DSPCLBLOCK>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :IV2613)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>

</ENVELOPE>');

SELECT ID --, x
    , c.value('(DSPVCHDATE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHDATE
    ,c.value('(DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT
    ,c.value('(DSPVCHTYPE/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPVCHTYPE
    ,c.value('(DSPINBLOCK/DSPVCHINQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHINQTY
    ,c.value('(DSPINBLOCK/DSPVCHINAMT/text())[1]','decimal(12,2)') AS DSPVCHINAMT 
    ,c.value('(DSPOUTBLOCK/DSPVCHOUTQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHOUTQTY 
    ,c.value('(DSPOUTBLOCK/DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT/text())[1]','decimal(12,2)') AS DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT
    ,c.value('(DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER
    --,c.value('(DSPCLBLOCK/DSPVCHCLQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHCLQTY 
    --,c.value('(DSPCLBLOCK/DSPVCHCLAMT/text())[1]','int') AS DSPVCHCLAMT 
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT xmldata.query('<ENVELOPE>
    {
        for $x in /ENVELOPE/DSPVCHDATE
        let $pos := count(ENVELOPE/DSPVCHDATE[. << $x]) + 1
        let $start := 1 + 7 * ($pos -1)
        let $end := 7 * $pos
        return <row>{/ENVELOPE/*[position() ge $start and position() le $end]}</row>
    }
    </ENVELOPE>')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY t1.x.nodes('/ENVELOPE/row') AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| ID | DSPVCHDATE |   DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT   | DSPVCHTYPE | DSPVCHINQTY | DSPVCHINAMT | DSPVCHOUTQTY | DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT | DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER |
+----+------------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1 | 16-4-2021  | PRASHANT MEHTA 359244 | Sale       | NULL        | NULL        | 1 Pcs        | 23046.88         | (No. :IV2612)    |
|  1 | 19-4-2021  | XYZ Company           | Purchase   | 1 Pcs       | 23437.50    | NULL         | NULL             | (No. :IV2613)    |
+----+------------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

**SQL #2**

Based on @Charlieface idea.

```
WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, xmldata
        , c.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS pos
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/ENVELOPE/DSPVCHDATE') AS t(c)
) 
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos")]/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHDATE
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 1]/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHITEMACCOUNT
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 2]/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHTYPE
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 3]/DSPVCHINQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHINQTY
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 3]/DSPVCHINAMT/text())[1]','decimal(12,2)') AS DSPVCHINAMT 
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 4]/DSPVCHOUTQTY/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHOUTQTY 
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 4]/DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPVCHNETTOUTAMT
    , c.value('(/ENVELOPE/*[sql:column("pos") + 6]/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/ENVELOPE') AS t(c);
```

Comment: Can't you shorten this by just returning each full set of values in one shot from XQuery?

Comment: Your point is not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: I feel like there must be a way of iterating the 7 rows with only one `CROSS APPLY`, by changing `.query` to `.nodes`

Comment: @Charlieface, Indeed, there is a solution based on your idea. I updated the answer.

Comment: Very nice.  I knew there was a way to do this with XQuery, but I don't know XQuery procs well enough to know what it was.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, And the XQuery based approach is definitely cleaner than handling XML as a string/VARCHAR() data type.

Comment: Agreed.  Though because so few people are even aware of XQuery procs, let alone know how to write/edit them, it might raise maintenance issues.  Nonetheless, I think that this perfectly illustrates why it isn't true that problems like this should always be handled outside of SQL Server.  This is arguably better than any external fix.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, So true. Please up-vote this suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali